# Cocoapods requires update each time on different computers through dropbox sync for bolts framework

Tags: ios, xcode, dropbox, cocoapods, bolts-framework

My setup:

- Xcode Project inside dropbox folder
- Cocoapods installed
- Parse is in my podfile which requires the Bolts framework

Every time I load up the workspace after having edited it from a different computer, Xcode complains about a duplicate interface definition for class 'BFAppLink' (which is from the Bolts framework). This is fixed by "pods update".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with Dropbox and the Parse pod. I investigated and found that CocoaPods keeps symlinks to your headers in ./Pods/Headers for some reasons Dropbox will actually copy the files on the other computer instead of just copying the symlink.

When you compile on your second computer there's 2 copies of the .h files so Xcode complains and won't compile until you run pod install (which will replace the duplicate .h files with the symlinks like it should). But then your other computers which compiled fine will get their symlinks replaced with duplicates of the header files.

The way I found around this was to add /Pods/Headers to the selective sync in Dropbox so they won't get sync. Then run pod install on all your computers and they should be able to compile.

I hope that helped

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that the pod update is rewriting your Xcode project and getting rid of the duplicate file imports. Instead of storing the project on Dropbox, can you store it in an actual SCM system like git, perhaps using a service like GitHub or BitBucket?

Comment: I use git and github. I use dropbox in addition for convenience and data duplication though. Because the changes are synced in the background, when I leave the office and go home, my laptop already has all the files synced, I don't need to pull and wait. Also, my images are excluded from git, so I'd still have to update those somehow if I didn't use dropbox.

Comment: What do you think is causing the duplicate file imports though, and why is it only with that one framework?

Comment: It's entirely possible that Dropbox doesn't know how to properly merge Xcode project files. It's trying to be smart by only syncing the changed parts of the file but that leads to a bad project file since it doesn't know that the result is supposed to look like. Of course, that's only speculation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of checklist that may solve your issue:

1. Is your entire project being copied into dropbox? Is your `/Pods` directory, `project.xcworkspace` being copied over?

If you copy the entire contents, for example, zip the entire project and unzip on a new machine, you should be able to run the project on any machine without cocoapods installed.

2. Is the bolt framework added via cocoapods? If you have a manual reference to the framework, the path may be different between version.
3. Are you using the same version of cocoapods on all your machines?

Different versions of cocoapods  between machines can cause issues such as the one you've observed.

```
$ pod --version
```

As jshier mentioned, consider using bitbucket or github for version a control. SourceTree is a great git client to match.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The Bolts framework is added automatically because the Parse framework requires it. I do think I'm currently on different versions 0.35 and 0.36 but I believe I was having issues when both were on 0.35. I'll try when I'm at the office tomorrow after updating and see if that fixes it.